# Platform Integration Works, but Telemetry doesn't get displayed Thingsboard PE 3.2.2

Tags: thingsboard

I successfully setup a Platform Integration, as you can see from the attached screenshot everything seems working fine, but in the device telemetry view nothing gets display.[image: Integration Status][image: Data Converter Succefull Output][image: Integration Succeful Output][image: No Telemetry Reported]

No telemetry is added to the device, despite the fact that Integration works as expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after having seemingly done the same thing: Installed a Thingsboard server from scratch following the instructions and then mocking the first device. I send the message via curl, I get a HTTP 200 OK reply, no errors in the log or anywhere else, it just seems as if it is either stuck or not handled at all. And I have no idea if it's a config problem with the device or if something (zookeeper, kafka...) is installed wrongly. You found anything out in between?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the Integration does not automatically save the anything. All it does is transform the data into a format that can be processed by the Rule Chain. Do you have a Device Profile set up for pHMeter? If you do, does that go to a specific Rule Chain? If it does, are you saving the telemetry in the Rule Chain? If yes to all, turn on debug mode and check each node to see where the problem is.

Comment: I ran into the same problem just following the most basic tutorial for a community edition on-premises installation. HTTP POST message is answered with 200 OK but no data is stored. Only following the manual, not having setup any special rule chains or device profiles. This is all so darn complex for us mere mortals...